# Dynamically placing images beside/on top of each other

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I currently am working on a project where I have two images of the human body, front and back. The images are set at `height: 80vh`. My Issue is this: I have been using bootstrap to flow the images beside each other when the screen is wide, and on top of each other when the screen is tall, with `col-xs-12 / col-md-6` classes, but these columns are not nearly as responsive as I'd like, as I really want the images next to each other unless they must flow on top of each other. How might I accomplish this? Thanks in advance!
[image]

---

Current HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" id="bodyMapFrontContainer">
        <img src="frontBodyImage.png" class="questionInputMethod" id="bodyImageFront" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" id="bodyMapBackContainer">
        <img src="backBodyImage.png" class="questionInputMethod" id="bodyImageBack" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

---

CSS:

```
.questionInputMethod {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align:center;
}

#bodyImageFront, #bodyImageBack {
    display:block;
    max-height: 60vh; 
    max-width: 90%;
    height:auto;
    width: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: You might have better luck if you can provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: I suggest rephrasing your question slightly as it currently reads like *my requirements are x, y and z, please make the provided code also do a, b and c*.

Comment: Just trying to be specific, but I see what you mean, I have fixed it. And also, I have posted code (though I don't know how helpful it will be, because it's really just two `img`s and a little style. My current solution works, but just isn't as responsive as I would like

Answer (score 0):

**WookieCoder** Is this something like what you are wanting to achieve here.

Have a look at this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0hxvby7/)** and resize it.
Here is the CSS to get the image in the block that has your 60vh height.

```
.bg-image { 
    background: #fff url('http://images.clipartpanda.com/sad-girl-stick-figure-image.png')center no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
}       
.block {
    min-height: 60vh;
}
```

When you want to space/block the main div over into the middle. Try using `col-sm-offset-x` class. This way when you have it show say in a small screen you can reposition it.

Does this help?

[image: resize image]

**Updated for added media breakpoint**

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0hxvby7/1/)** with the added breakpoint at 400px.
You can remove the code I added to show when it uses `col-xxs-12`.

[image]

Comment: The idea of using a col-*-offset is great, I will use that. The problem again comes in, the images are taking up more room than they need to. (ex. if the images are 200px wide by 350px tall, they should be next to each other until the screen is 400px wide, and this example again uses the bootstrap columns, which are only responsive at a select few points). I don't know if that makes any sense....

Comment: Hi, It sounds like we just need to add another **media breakpoint** to do what you want here. Do you need help with this?

Comment: So you think I should just pass a few more breakpoints? (I can do that, I just didn't know if that was the best way)

Comment: HI, Have a look at my main post , I added another fiddle with the breakpoint, See if that works for you. If you don't think this might not be the best way... describe a little more what you are looking for. I can then see how to help.